# Dagger 2.28 Unwanted WRITE_EXTERNAL_FILE_PERMISSION

Tags: android, permissions, dagger-2, file-permissions, dagger

We recently bumped a few libraries and also dagger version to 2.28 and when we wanted to publish the new version at Google play we faced this error:

> Users that have the APK with version code XXX may need to accept one or more of the android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE and android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, which may result in them not upgrading to this version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This was apparently added accidentally to dagger because of minApi < 4 which caused implicitly addition of this permission to the apps using it. Updating to dagger 2.28.3 solved the problem!